# Difficulties retrieving List<int> within List<List<int>>

Tags: c#, list, int

I am having trouble with the below code:

```
foreach (var result in results)
{
    foreach (int individualresult in result)
    {
         //Operation
    }
}
```

'results' is a `List<List<int>>` and I am trying to retrieve each integer from each list within the 'results' list of lists (sorry if that's confusing), however when I run the code no errors are received but it doesn't get any further than the first line.
I've put it in a 'try catch' and it doesn't pick up any exceptions or errors so I am flummoxed as to why it isn't working. Additionally I have tried changing `var` to `List<int>` but that didn't change anything either.

Any and all help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Show how you get the list please, the code you posted should work

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. We don't have enough information to help you at the moment.

Comment: I assume your `List<List<int>>` is empty

Comment: Try to debug, set a breakpoint at the first curly bracket inside your outer foreach loop and then check results, If results is empty the inner foreach loop will never be reached. If it is not empty do the same for the inner foreach loop and check result, if that is empty your operations will never be reached. If both are not the case provide feedback again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in a Console-Application and check the Output. I assume that ether your results is empty or that each individual List in your results is empty.

```
Console.WriteLine("Start");
if (results == null || !results.Any())
    Console.WriteLine("No result received!");

foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("new result-set");
    if (result == null || !result.Any())
        Console.WriteLine("    Result: Empty list!");

    foreach (var individualresult in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("   Result: " + individualresult);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("End");
Console.Readline();
```

Answer (score 0):

See this example it might help you

```
    class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<int> list1d = new List<int>();
        List<List<int>> list2d = new List<List<int>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            list1d = new List<int>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                list1d.Add(i * j + i);
            }
            list2d.Add(list1d);
        }


        foreach (var result in list2d)
        {

            foreach (var i  in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }

        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```